# Need an help to decode this html file

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to decode this html file when i open that html file it shows me the following data

```
‹í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"~ãä7NÏÛEyô'iúxžg3þ~o‹¶Ì^Ï«ÕY›n§O²æmÞ>¾+k›²X¾Më¼üì£¦½.ófžçíGé¼ÎÏé~s¯êt ¯Ôpç~<öß—ùò¢ÓçŸ|àš ß+¾O/‹3à`¡ß›zJm<ˆô¡×ì—˜_õ—Çw=Š=¾kçëñ¤š]§mµZ bùÙÇ§Ó2kšÏ>Â72‹¥“lúö¢®ÖËÙgï ï–ÕE5¾(Î?Jyé Ûj»ÎWyÖ>J—•þúQZ-Ÿ±>ûH©¶õ±”ÕuuõbÄ õ6›”yzUÌÚùgïîìüî§“ªžåõgïÐ(ò²\e³Y±¼°7«lª+€©íïøKèbžÇÅâ"%ZæpjëlI€j":#d1xpÿãtžóö³ïQ†Yñÿû€©›4+‹ "x>&î’?'UÛV ‡©¶ÐL¯_wÜò„£—Ètˆ3>ît,ìññe^7$q ¤?™~:Þé }Ôíb¨Ó Ÿ£éçù"g¢Ø{¢@8ï3úÄ½E˜öô«×2 ÷GSšè¼þH þÑÃßý£€¨íí–Ä«õQjþÀŸ3ÿO|À u¾>Úé€Ú¥,,y:å!¸:±^ý¨ß$MŸ¿þ½Nßt?§¡:ÈCBÈCÍð3þÈPlG [¸]ÿêÐË£¢ _®é[áúÂ<Òß†yéï @¤ 'üŸw¨,O ãÅqWþ¶8îîu‘”‡Q}A_ý®ÛÛé"+–)MâUÑÎÓiEØ,Ûíí((zƒv÷±=[.-¶LŸÛ=ñ¾Ð€fÙºÝo¢Ûçuž/&–%ZÓß–x½ ö¦ =Ã-Ð†&Ï¦FiŒH5¦ ècP¨@y@ó;ÝÑ·43 wåo3 wïLøæ]ðF.ŠÙ¬ÌI{Ñ¬ëG%Y·^ÖÕl=mÓÙ"'é›û-ÈÑ‹õb’×Cßþnw¿Zð³‚oU—þnéëõB¾ƒ¬C˜7£[>nÚl9Ëê7äé·.cm‡+qôäË/ß¼¥o~Ÿ—§»ÔËìv€ýÔ‡¾ÿáøáíA† | ½N¾|þúåñ òÕöµ?îîèñDû˜  ÓêÝMìLmndzjÃÂ3Ô‚¾Ç0¥OFðýsí‹üàkx14$Ý‡hµñ{j1Ù ZÀ/X’œ|ö»‡ìJž‚óMù8Žð7¤3/ zÇY³‚GúEµnòŠ\|kÏéà/Êù ‡îÝ5™?nÁ­‡^5o Ÿ|„ðG„öòšÉ“@®üúñÝl# hö6Q‘¾¾ÕäÓ¯OüMzOÏ{bM©alécí·û}Ó}Â äm÷!}ä^£?Ì ô+7Å_$_ÆÐ¯óH´úÿ¤:ÍXº
```

response header of that html file contains following info
**Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET**

Please help guys
Current language i am using is c# but language is not an barrier
 link for that html file can be found over here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7czdsz0iSPjNVg1OUp1LVhFQUE

Comment: You need to read about decompressing gzip strings in c#

Comment: You asked pretty much the same question yesterday - we pointed you in the direction - have you tried anything yet? If so please show the code you have - then you may get some responses.

Comment: i have tried most of the options available online to decompress gz i am stuck o this from past week .. i  have tried  this code available on this site with some modifiaction https://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream

Comment: So show your code & explain what is not working as you expect - SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: paul apology for that i have tried most of the codes available on stack overflow some of the code like byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString); and other one is this  byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
            byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default, utf8Bytes);
            string uf8converted = Encoding.Default.GetString(isoBytes);
           // var anyString=System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(str);
            CompressStringToFile(@"C:\Users\quality_digital_2\Documents\compass\new.gz", anyString);

Comment: convert parameters  are shuffled by me for trial and error.. and compressto stringfile method is the one which i have found on dot.net pearl which take byte as an parameters and create a gzip file which then i used to pass to the gzip decompressor for an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **System.IO.Compression.GZipStream** and create a method to decompress the data:

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] zipData)
{
    using (var zipStream = GZipStream(new MemoryStream(zipData), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        const int size = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            while (count > 0);

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use **File.ReadAllBytes** method to get a byte[] which can be consumend by the Decompress method:

```
    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("201.html");
    byte[] decompressed = Decompress(file);
    File.WriteAllBytes("201.decompressed.html", decompressed);
```

I just successfully tested the method with your sample file.

Comment: My bad  i have also tested with the same method Thanks for the help i was doing one wrong thing instead of passing file directly i was passing the file to compressor method to make a file with gz  extension and then passing the file to decompressor which is giving me an bad output this time i passed the file directly to the decompressor and it worked the file was already compressed i was doing wrong thing

Answer (score 0):

so this is  my finalcode for thanks for the help guys

```
  public static void gzipdecompressor()
    {
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\quality_digital_2\Documents\Projects\224.html");
        byte[] decompressed = Decompress(file);
        Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(decompressed);
        var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(decompressed);
        Console.WriteLine(str);


    }
public static byte[] gzipDecompress(byte[] gzip)
    {

        using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip),
            CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            const int size = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```